# htaccess not redirecting for filename.php?poi_id=362

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having problems with some files not redirecting. In particular, some php files.

Example:

- http://www.gojapango.com/travel/japan.php?poi_id=362

should go to

- https://www.gojapango.com/places/okinawa-prefecture/kadena/airport/kadena-air-base/

Running on an Apache server.

I have tried the following in the root .htaccess:

```
redirect 301 /travel/japan.php?poi_id=362 {as above}/places/okinawa-prefecture/kadena/airport/kadena-air-base/
```

When this didn't work, I removed that line from the root .htaccess file and put the following in the /travel/.htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /japan.php?poi_id=362 {as above}/places/okinawa-prefecture/kadena/airport/kadena-air-base/
```

which didn't work, so I tried without the `/` in from of the japan.php, but that didn't work either as it just goes to the original page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect 301 doesnt work for urls with query strings. You need to use RewriteCond and RewriteRule

e.g

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/travel/japan.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^poi_id=362$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gojapango.com/places/okinawa-prefecture/kadena/airport/kadena-air-base/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. That at least explains it for me. I ended up having to add a field to the table and import the data into that. Then modifying the code in the japan.php file to do a redirection in php.